# Compare records in database where one column exists but another doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare two "lists" in same table and get records where `customerId` exists but `storeid` doesn't exist for that `customerid`.

Lists (table definition)

```
name             listid   storeid   customerid

BaseList           1        10         100
BaseList           1        11         100
BaseList           1        11         102


NewList            2        11         100
NewList            2        12         102
NewList            2        12         103
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    NewList.*
FROM 
    Lists NewList
LEFT JOIN 
    Lists BaseList ON BaseList.customerid = NewList.customerid 
WHERE 
    BaseList.listid = 1
    AND NewList.listid = 2
    AND NewList.storeid <> BaseList.storeid
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM Lists c
                    WHERE BaseList.customerid = c.customerid
                      AND BaseList.storeid = c.storeid
                      AND c.listid = 2)
```

Current result:

```
NewList 2 11 100 
NewList 2 12 102
```

But i'm expecting to only get the result

```
NewList 2 12 102
```

as customerid 100 with storeid 11 exists.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a389de/3)

Comment: in fiddle, second row is `'BaseList',1,11,100` whereas in sample it is  `BaseList           1        11         101`. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Utsav sorry that should be 1 11 100

Comment: Btw: This is a very good question! Sample data, own attempt, Fiddle... expected output... voted it up!

Comment: Seconded. Adding fiddle really helps.

Comment: Didn't the answers help you? Is this still open? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table definition contains a column `Name` (as you said), then the statement below returns your result.

I didn't understand your select statement.

```
SELECT *
from @table
WHERE NAME = 'NewList'
  AND customerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM @table WHERE NAME = 'BaseList')
  AND storeID NOT IN (SELECT storeID FROM @table WHERE NAME = 'BaseList')
```

Comment: Thanks for your respons, but im thinking of doing this without putting this into a temp table.

Comment: Hi @Henrik, I think this temp table is just a residue of the answerers test. Just change the `@table` to your actual table's name and test it...

Comment: I used @Table to test if it works. You should change it with your table name.

Answer (score 1):

This dynamic pivot will show you all your list values and where else the same combination exists:

I add one more group:

```
insert into Lists(name, listid, storeid, customerid) values('AnotherNew',3,11,100);
insert into Lists(name, listid, storeid, customerid) values('AnotherNew',3,11,102);
insert into Lists(name, listid, storeid, customerid) values('AnotherNew',3,10,100);
```

Here's the statement:

EDIT: This new statement is - I think - better as it comes over the distinct combinations of customerid and storeid

```
DECLARE @listNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + name + ']'
    FROM Lists
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'');

DECLARE @SqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'
WITH DistinctCombinations AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT customerid,storeid
    FROM Lists AS l
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
SELECT DistinctCombinations.*
      ,OtherExisting.name AS OtherName
      ,CASE WHEN l.listid IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE ''X'' END AS ExistingValue
FROM DistinctCombinations
LEFT JOIN Lists AS l ON DistinctCombinations.customerid=l.customerid AND DistinctCombinations.storeid=l.storeid
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT x.name 
    FROM Lists AS x 
    WHERE x.customerid=l.customerid 
      AND x.storeid=l.storeid
) AS OtherExisting
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ExistingValue) FOR OtherName IN (' +  @ListNames + ') 
) AS p';

EXEC(@SqlCmd);
```

The result

```
customerid  storeid AnotherNew  BaseList    NewList
100            10      X           X         NULL
100            11      X           X         X
102            11      X           X         NULL
102            12      NULL        NULL      X
103            12      NULL        NULL      X
```

This is the approach before:

```
DECLARE @listNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + name + ']'
    FROM Lists
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'');

DECLARE @SqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'
WITH DistinctLists AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT listid
    FROM Lists AS l
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
SELECT l.*
      ,OtherExisting.name AS OtherName
      ,CASE WHEN l.listid IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE ''X'' END AS ExistingValue
FROM DistinctLists
INNER JOIN Lists AS l ON DistinctLists.listid= l.listid
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT x.name 
    FROM Lists AS x 
    WHERE x.listid<>l.listid 
      AND x.customerid=l.customerid 
      AND x.storeid=l.storeid
) AS OtherExisting
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ExistingValue) FOR OtherName IN (' +  @ListNames + ') 
) AS p';

EXEC(@SqlCmd);
```

And that is the result:

```
name      listid    storeid customerid  AnotherNew  BaseList    NewList
AnotherNew  3         10       100         NULL        X         NULL
AnotherNew  3         11       100         NULL        X         X
AnotherNew  3         11       102         NULL        X         NULL
BaseList    1         10       100         X           NULL      NULL
BaseList    1         11       100         X           NULL      X
BaseList    1         11       102         X           NULL      NULL
NewList     2         11       100         X           X         NULL
```

Comment: @krtek :-)  We had a similar problem too... I hate such grouped key-value-pair-tables. They are used in so many applications / databases. The question brought me to the idea, that the OP had problems with duplicated list members. This approach will show existing duplicates... And - just for fun - I like such things ;-)  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Tested this in Fiddle. Please test it with some more data. But for your input it seems to be working correctly.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a389de/32)**</kbd>

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (
    SELECT n.*
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM lists
        WHERE NAME = 'NewList'
        ) n
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM lists
        WHERE NAME = 'BaseList'
        ) b ON b.storeid = n.storeid
    WHERE b.listid IS NULL
    ) c
WHERE c.customerid IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT customerid
        FROM lists
        WHERE NAME = 'BaseList'
        )
```